# Can't find the configure features wizard in TFS 2018

Tags: tfs

I've installed TFS 2018 and I'm looking to run the configure features wizard but can't seem to find it. It isn't where they describe in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/configure-features-after-upgrade?view=tfs-2018.

I didn't do an upgrade but after installing I did customize the template. The documentation pointed me to the previous link with regards to how to apply certain template changes to existing projects. After making those types of template changes it sounded like I should expect to see the configure features option available somewhere but if that's true I cannot find them.

See the section "Compatible for quick updating" here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/on-premises-xml-process-model?view=tfs-2018

Can someone point me to where that feature resides now in the new interface?

Comment: Did you fresh install TFS2018 instead of upgrade your exist TFS server version from old (such as 2017) to TFS2018?

Comment: Hi Sacrilege, any update on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see the Configure Features option, it means there are no features to configure. If you're upgrading from TFS 2015 or 2017 and everything was already configured, then there might not be anything that needs to be upgraded.

Comment: It wasn't an upgrade but after installing I did update the process template and the documentation sounded like I should see the configure features option available somewhere after I did: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/on-premises-xml-process-model?view=tfs-2018

Answer (score 0):

The Configure Features Wizard detects which features have and haven't been configured. Most new features include additions or changes to work item types (WITs), categories, or process configuration. New features are **introduced with different updates to Team Foundation Server (TFS).**

After you installed TFS2018, there are no  configure features wizard simply means there are no features need to be update/configure for your team projects.

Comment: It wasn't an upgrade but after installing I did update the process template and the documentation sounded like I should see the configure features option available somewhere after I did: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/on-premises-xml-process-model?view=tfs-2018